# Multiple sessions on one computer overriding each other

Tags: php

I have created a forgot password function and everything works great as long as one session is active at a time. When multiple sessions are run, they start overriding each other. i'm not sure how to solve this. i thought by passing seesion variable, i could identify the sessions by email. If anyone can teach me what i am doing wrong, or how to correctly run multiple sessions, it would greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
    function forgot_submit(){
        GLOBAL $db;
        if (isset($_GET['forgot']) && $_GET['forgot'] == 'true') {
            $email     = $_POST['forgot_password'];
            $token     = "1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
            $token     = str_shuffle($token);
            $token     = substr($token, 0, 10);
            mail($email, "Password Reset", "To reset you password, please enter this code: $token", "from: noreply@yahbang.com");
            $Query = $db->prepare("UPDATE user SET forgotToken='$token' WHERE email='$email'");
            $Query->execute();
            if ($Query) {
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                echo json_encode(['error' => 'success', 'msg' => 'resetPassword.php']);
            }

        }
    }////close forgot submit///////////
    forgot_submit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A session is a hunk of data that you want to associate with a particular user (whether user is authenticated, user name, or something else you don't want to fetch from database on every page load). Every page load needs a `session_start()` to open the data, which will be empty until a `$_SESSION` key is added. The PHP engine identifies each session by a cookie variable. If you're only setting `$_SESSION['email']` in one browser, you will get the same answer.

That being said, once a user decides they need a new password, you should immediately destroy the session: [`session_destroy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) so the user is forced to logout and reauthenticate.

Additionally, in your next upgrade, prepared statements should have [bound values or parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) with named or question mark placeholders.